# How to write CSV to Azure Storage Gen2 with Databricks(Python)

Tags: azure-databricks

I would like write reqular CSV file to Storage, but what I get is folder "sample_file.csv" and 4 files under it. How to create normal csv file from data frame to Azure Storage Gen2?

I'm happy with any advice or link to article.

df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true").csv(TargetDirectory + "/sample_file.csv")

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to save a single file into adls gen2 using Spark DataFrameWriter.In fact, the DF writer saves data to an HDFS filesystem based on Azure Data Lake. So your data will be persisted as a folder and some partition files (part-**).

You can try this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, FileUtil, Path}
```

create a fileSystem :

```
def getFileSystem(containerPath: Path): FileSystem =
FileSystem
  .get(
    new URI(containerPath.toString),
    hadoopConfiguration
  )
```

use the FileUtil to copy your processed file from a container to another destination :

```
FileUtil.copy(
  getFileSystem(sourceContainerPath),
  blobSourcePath,
  getFileSystem(destinationContainerPath),
 blobDestinationPath,
  true, // true to ovewrite 
  true, // true to delete source file
  hadoopConfiguration
)
```

and of course do not forget to set the necessary configuration to your sparkSession.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration when creating your SparkSession.

```
hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.wasbs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")
hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure.account.key.storageAccountName.blob.core.windows.net","storageAccountKeyValue")
```

This is not the best way to but if it's really mandatory for to have a single file then you have to look for a work around. I told you what i did when i got the same issue.

Hope this helps.